# flutter_downloader plugin is not working on existing project

Tags: java, android, flutter, download

I want to implement the download functionality to my existing app but it throws an exception and I cannot figure out why.

I freshly created a new flutter project and installed the flutter_downloader plugin and it works fine but when I implement the feature in the same way in my existing application, it throws me an error.

The stack trace is here:

```
2019-11-02 13:11:44.655 13280-13280/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 13280
java.lang.IllegalStateException: registrar.activity() must not be null
    at co.paystack.flutterpaystack.FlutterPaystackPlugin$Companion.registerWith(FlutterPaystackPlugin.kt:18)
    at co.paystack.flutterpaystack.FlutterPaystackPlugin.registerWith(Unknown Source:2)
    at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:30)
    at com.example.app.FlutterCustomApp.registerWith(FlutterCustomApp.java:10)
    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.startBackgroundIsolate(DownloadWorker.java:124)
    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.access$000(DownloadWorker.java:59)
    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker$1.run(DownloadWorker.java:97)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

This is my custom application class:

```
public class FlutterCustomApp extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
@Override
public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
}
```

}

And I specified the class name in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file as well.

But when I initiate a download task, above exception is thrown and the app is crashed. I still couldn't figure out why this is happening.

- compileSdkVersion: 28
- compileSdkVersion: 21
- targetSdkVersion: 28
- gradle version: 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Since flutter engine is required to communicate with the native android that depends on the android lifecycle (if you take a look the [FlutterActivity](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity.html)), the registry of the plugin should start register on the activity instead of the application class.

You should call the plugin registration on the first Splash Activity or BaseActivity onCreate, if there is no other specific concern or reason like JNI initialization or Flutter engine related config changes:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

Comment: Then how does this freshly created flutter project is working and not existing project? I followed the same documentation on my old and new projects and the new one works but the old one. Both projects support AndroidX as well.

Comment: That's weird. Just want to confirm is your android project that automatically generated inside your flutter project is using Application class to register or you have tried to use the custom application class run with the flutter project which is successful? As usually automatically project creation should register on the Activity class like that one I paste.

Comment: In my successful project, I created the Application class manually and specified its name in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: In my failing project, I tried 2 methods. One is the same method I mentioned earlier. The next one is to use the same MainActivity class to implement the above method. Both are failing with different errors

Comment: Would you mind also pasting the other error log? Just want to compare if that may have any hints.

Comment: `2019-11-02 20:33:13.609 2925-2925/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 2925
    java.lang.AssertionError: The Application must be implemented PluginRegistrantCallback
        at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.startBackgroundIsolate(DownloadWorker.java:106)
        at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.access$000(DownloadWorker.java:59)
        at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker$1.run(DownloadWorker.java:97)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.di`

Comment: It tells me to implement `PluginRegistrantCallback` even though I have already implemented in the MainActivity.java. I will post that code as well

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity implements PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }

}`